# Countdown Timer - Remove DIV when reaches Zero

Tags: html, timer, countdown

I would like to know how I can have an on screen countdown timer, when it reaches zero it removes a specific DIV.

Basically I am designing an offer page which is a one time offer and they must respond to it within a time frame or else it will disappear forever.

I have a div called #offer-wrapper and below a div called #offer-timer. The timer in the second div should cause the first div to be removed from the page.

Could start with getting a HTML/JS countdown script but from there I am lost, please advise thank you :)

EDIT. Also something to stop the user from just refreshing the page if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the window.setInterval combined with a simple function to update a global variable and then jQuery's .remove() function (or even just set the CSS to display:none)

```
var time = 60;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test()
{
    //update time
    time -=1;
    //update the div to show the time
    $('#testDiv').html(time); 

    //hide the div if the time is 0
    if(time == 0)        
    {
        $('#testDiv').remove();
    }
}
```

jsFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/9sAce/
    ​

Comment: Thank you, how can I have it so the user cannot refresh to see the offer again? Cookies somehow?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you may not be able to use Cookies.  Cookies can easily be cleared on the client side.  If you don't have a logged in account, then you could consider saving the state in a DB by IP...but then its easy to change and IP too.  The only way to ensure 100% that the same user account doesn't get the "offer" twice would be to fire off an AJAX request when the timer expires to update a DB that that logged in account has already seen that offer.    Check out [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.fn.countDown = function(settings, to) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
            startFontSize : '40px',
            endFontSize : '12px',
            duration : 1000,
            startNumber : 10,
            endNumber : 0,
            callBack : function() {
            }
        }, settings);
        return this.each(function() {

            if (!to && to != settings.endNumber) {
                to = settings.startNumber;
            }

            // Set the countdown to the starting number
            $(this).text(to).css('fontSize', settings.startFontSize);

            // Loopage
            $(this).animate({
                'fontSize' : settings.endFontSize
            }, settings.duration, '', function() {
                if (to > settings.endNumber + 1) {
                    $(this).css('fontSize', settings.startFontSize).text(to - 1).countDown(settings, to - 1);
                } else {
                    settings.callBack(this);
                }
            });

        });
    };

    $('#countdown').countDown({
        startNumber : 100,
        callBack : function(me) {
            $('#countdown').remove();
            alert("TIME IS OVER!!");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I have it so the user cannot refresh to see the offer again? Cookies somehow?

Comment: you can put your timer code in window.location.reload() as well. I guess it will work. NOt sure though!

Comment: Sorry I have VERY limited knowledge of javascript. Could you eloborate on that?